# Not condition does not work in python for loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to get info from a website by an interval. I wrote two loops into each other. Somehow not condition in second while loop does not work and makes it an infinite loop. Although values seem to be same. They even calculate. What am I doing wrong?

```
import requests
import time

buy = 0.0
sell = 0.0
tidnew = 0
counter = -1

main_api = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1'

trades = '/trades/'
etc = 'ETCUSD'

getorders = main_api+trades+etc

json_orderget = requests.get(getorders).json()
json_orderline = json_orderget[0]
tid = json_orderline["tid"]

if json_orderline["type"] == 'buy':
    buy = float(json_orderline["amount"])
else:
    sell = float(json_orderline["amount"])

time.sleep(1)

while True:
    print("first while loop")
    json_orderget = requests.get(getorders).json()
    json_orderline = json_orderget[0]
    tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]
    int(tidnew)
    counter += 1
    tid = int(tid)
    tidnew = int(tidnew)

    if tid == tidnew:
        print("Tid's are equal.")

    while tid != tidnew:
        print("Second while loop")
        json_orderline = json_orderget[counter]
        price = json_orderline["price"]
        tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]
        if json_orderline["type"] == 'buy':
            buy += float(json_orderline["amount"])
        else:
            sell += float(json_orderline["amount"])

        print("New price is: " + str(price))
        print("New tid is: " + str(tid))
        print("Buy volume is: " + str(buy))
        print("Sell volume is: " + str(sell))
        counter += 1

    tid = tidnew
    print("tid is: " + str(tid))
    tid = int(tid)
    counter = -1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: How can you expect anything but an infinite loop if you write `while True` and never `break` the loop? What do you think is the stop-condition there?

Comment: *int(tidnew)* is a useless statement when the result is nowhere assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean?

```
while tid != tidnew:
    print("first while loop")
    json_orderget = requests.get(getorders).json()
    json_orderline = json_orderget[0]
    tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]
    int(tidnew)
    counter += 1
    tid = int(tid)
    tidnew = int(tidnew)

    if tid == tidnew:
        print("Tid's are equal.")
```

I don't know what your condition of the while should be, but "while True" is an infinite loop.

Comment: If the program outputs "Tid's are equal." , the loop is going to finish. If not the condition is wrong. But there is no problem with the != operator.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check what datatypes `tid` and `tidnew` are.

I think `tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]` sets `tidnew` to a string, while `tid` is an integer. Try using `tidnew = int(json_orderline["tid"])` instead. (Or add `tidnew = int(tidnew)` after reading the json data.)

Answer (score 0):

After I posted this and I had read the first answer it ocurred to me. I try to explain my problem as clear as possible:
The reason for this code is to pull trades from a trading site. For an answer I get a massive list of trades containing info about a trade. Code pulls it first and then starts to compare if the first "tid" entry in the list is the same if not it takes some data from the first list entry and then move on to the next until it finds the matching "tid".
My problem was that I overwrote the tid entry with wromg value. It should have been the first entry, what is the latest trade. But it wrote the last matching "tid" and that made the values unequal.
The magic happens with tidfirst variable.
New updated code:

```
import requests
import time

buy = 0.0
sell = 0.0
tidnew = 0
tid = 0
tidfirst = 0
counter = -1

main_api = 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1'

trades = '/trades/'
etc = 'ETCUSD'

getorders = main_api+trades+etc

json_orderget = requests.get(getorders).json()
json_orderline = json_orderget[0]
tid = json_orderline["tid"]
if json_orderline["type"] == 'buy':
    buy = float(json_orderline["amount"])
else:
    sell = float(json_orderline["amount"])


time.sleep(1)

while True:
    print("first while loop")
    json_orderget = requests.get(getorders).json()
    json_orderline = json_orderget[0]
    tidfirst = json_orderline["tid"]
    tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]
    counter += 1

    if tid == tidnew:
        print("Tid's are equal.")

    while tid != tidnew:
        print("Second while loop")
        json_orderline = json_orderget[counter]
        price = json_orderline["price"]
        tidnew = json_orderline["tid"]
        if json_orderline["type"] == 'buy':
            buy += float(json_orderline["amount"])
        else:
            sell += float(json_orderline["amount"])

        print("New price is: " + str(price))
        print("New tid is: " + str(tid))
        print("Buy volume is: " + str(buy))
        print("Sell volume is: " + str(sell))
        counter += 1

    tid = tidfirst
    print("tid is: " + str(tid))
    tid = int(tid)
    counter = -1
    time.sleep(1)
```